# Rationale for a convention: Why use the semiperimeter in Heron's formula?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, convention

Heron's formula says that the area of a triangle whose sides have lengths $a, b, c$ is $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ where $s=(a+b+c)/2$ is the semiperimeter.  It can also be stated by saying that the area is $\frac14\sqrt{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)}$.  Is there a substantial reason to prefer the first form, using the semiperimeter, over the second?  It seems as if that's the only form I've seen in published sources.

(Either way, it's the simplest function of $a$, $b$, $c$ that is 2nd-degree homogeneous and is equal to $0$ whenever the three vertices are on a common line or at a common point.)

**PS inspired by comments:**

Let's compare lengths:

$$
\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\text{ where }s=(a+b+c)/2\text{ is the semiperimeter}
$$
$$
\phantom{\frac{\vert}{}}\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\text{ where $s$ is the semiperimeter}
$$
$$
\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\text{ where }s=(a+b+c)/2
$$
$$
\frac 1 4 \sqrt{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)}
$$

Comment: The formula with $s$ is shorter.

Comment: $s$ is a pretty common variable when doing geometrical (in)equalities. Since the formula is shorter and doesn't have the $\frac 14$ in front of it, I think it's preferred to use the notation with $s$.

Comment: Is it shorter when you include ". . . where $s=(a+b+c)/2$ is the semiperimeter"?  (I'm not sure how to measure length of a formula for such purposes.)  The form without $s$ has the fraction $1/4$ and the form with $s$ has the fraction $1/2$, in the definition of "semiperimeter".

Comment: @Ragnar : If you can state the most important dozen-or-so inequalities of the sort you mention, then maybe you could make your comment plus that list into an answer.

Comment: @Ragnar : Sorry: I meant "(in)equalities".

Comment: @MichaelHardy, in retrospect, there aren't that much equalities that really use $s$. When solving problems, it comes up pretty often anyway (more then $2s$ i think). Also, I think it's easier to write $s$ and $2s$ instead of $\frac 12 q$ and $q$ where $q=a+b+c$.

Comment: The area of the triangle is $rs$ where $r$ is the inradius. The radii of the excircles have convenient expressions in terms of $s$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle

Comment: Same as Mark Bennet: Area relates, say, to incircle (and excircle) of a triangle. There's a bunch of formulae where $s$ comes in handy (or just looks better, eventually, anyway). For example: $r=\frac{A}{s},$ where $r$ is inradius, $A$ area, $s$ semiperimeter. Why not keep Heron's area using $s$? ;)

Comment: @Gerry Myerson This discussion makes me wonder: Does the following formula for the volume of a tetrahedron (in terms of its edge lengths) have a similarly nifty factorization?  
$\frac{\sqrt{
AD(-A+B+C-D+E+F)+BE(A-B+C+D-E+F)+CF(A+B-C+D+E-F)
-(ABC+AEF+BFD+CDE)
}}{12}$, (where $A=a^2,\dots, F=f^2$; and the side of length a is opposite that of length d, ditto b and e, ditto c and f)

Comment: It is regrettable that the circumscribed and inscribed circle (or "excircle" and "incircle", as they often seem to be called now) theorems are not generally taught in pre-calculus anymore.  The introduction of $ \ s \ $ ends up looking like a completely arbitrary choice in re-writing expressions such as Heron's Formula, instead of being a rather "natural" quantity to use.  (It also makes the derivation of the Formula a bit horrific -- see, for example, most pre-calculus texts or videos such as the one on KhanAcademy...)

Comment: @Senex, I don't know.

Comment: I can also attest that, from a practical viewpoint, it is considerably quicker to compute the area of a triangle using Heron than the other expression.  If it's faster for me on a calculator, it was also presumably preferable for people living in the "long-hand era"...  (Incidentally, these formulas were considered terrible centuries ago, in the days when powers of a variable were still strongly tied to geometric interpretations, because a fourth-degree polynomial under the radical is being used to represent an area.)

Comment: Personally, I like the semiperimeter-less version of the formula. Familiarity with the all-$a$-$b$-$c$ version makes it easier to spot when (the square of) area factors-out from some crazy expression in Mathematica. In that regard, being able to recognize $$-a^4-b^4-c^4+2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2c^2a^2$$ comes in handy, too. Also, the $s$-less formula just seems more likely to inspire one to wonder *What's up with the pattern-breaking all-plus factor?* ... which adds a bit of "Ah-ha!" to  [Brahmagupta's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta's_formula) for the area of a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: To reinforce @RecklessReckoner 's point, the Heron version has both the fewest multiplications/divisions (5, as opposed to the 9 needed for the expanded-out symmetric quartic version),  and the fewest additions/subtractions (5, as opposed to the 8 that the proper a/b/c form uses) of the expressions for computing the area; in that sense it is the shortest formula.

Comment: OK, looking at the correspondence continuing to be exchanged on this question, I'll offer one other consideration, related to simplicity:  Heron's Formula is much easier to _remember_ correctly.  Even having _derived_ the area formula without the semiperimeter, I find it easier to recall and write "Heron" down than having to keep in mind the presence of the cyclic permutation of letters in three of the factors (which, actually, I just noticed).  [Hmm, maybe I _can_ remember the alternate expression better now.  Heron is still easier to write out and calculate with...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason I think is simplicity:

$$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

Is much more simple than:

$$A=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(b+c−a)(c+a−b)(a+b−c)}$$

I see in the comments that you say we have to add $\text{where } 2s=a+b+c$, in the standard form, and so the length of the two forms become the same. However, this is a useless argument. Continuing with the logic we must add, $\text{where a,b,c  are lengths of sides of the triangle}.$ This, everyone will agree that is pointless, and will unnecessarily increase the length and apparent complexity of the formula.

The same goes with $s$ here, we do need to add $s$ is this and this. Anyone studying geometry will immediately recognize that $s$ stands for the semi-perimeter. For example, we would never recognize in a geometry question, $p$ as the perimeter, however when we see $s$, the first thought that comes is the semi-perimeter. Hence, I think, its a bit stubborn to add that part as you have done in the postscript, and then compare lengths.

And this said, the point is not on length but on how simple the formula is. The better form must be the one that allows more easily to do what the formula is about, that is calculating the area. Let us take an example with a $13, 14, 15$ triangle, and calculate using both forms as I would have done myself with a pen and paper:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\text{Form 1} & \text{     Form 2} \\
\hline
{ s=\frac{13+14+15}{2}=21 \\
  s - a=21 - 13=8 \\
  s - b=21 - 14=7 \\
  s - c=21 - 15=6 \\
  \text{So, } A=\sqrt{21\cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 6}=\sqrt{3 \cdot (7 \cdot 7) \cdot 2 \cdot 4  \cdot 2 \cdot  3} \\
   =7\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 2=84 } & {a + b + c =13+14+15=42 \\
 a + b - c =13+14-15=27-15=12 \\
 a + c - b =13+15-14=28-14=14 \\
 b + c - a =14+15-13=28-16=16 \\
 \text{So, } A=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{42\cdot 12 \cdot 14 \cdot 16}\\=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2 \cdot 21 \cdot 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 8} \\=\sqrt{21 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8}=7\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 2=84}\\ 
\end{array}
$$

Even with small dimensions, we can see that the first form has an advantage. We can calculate $s$ easily and then $s-a$, $s-b$, .. as its just a subtraction of two terms. However, calculating $a + b - c$, $a + c - b$ .. are three terms calculation are very unrelated to each other. This becomes clearer when the sides are larger and variable. Thus, we can see that the standard form has advantages, its easier to use, write and state. There is one more important aspect.

There is an important area formula in terms of $s$, using the inradius, $A =rs$, where r is the inradius. If we draw the incircle, and the sides divided by the points of tangency can be conveniently expressed in terms of $s$. There are many examples where properties of triangles could be reprsented in terms of $s$, and without using $s$, it would be very untidy. As an example, the standard form allows a convenient expression of the inradius, whle the other form would give a very untidy expression:

$$r=\frac{A}{s}=\frac{\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}{s}=\sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{s}}$$

Generalizations of the Herons formula, like the [Brahmagupta's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula), or even the [Bretschneider's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretschneider%27s_formula), which gives us the area of a general convex quadrilateral:

$$A=\sqrt {(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d) - abcd  \cdot \cos^2 \left(\frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2}\right)}$$

This is a very convenient and simple expression. However, if we replace $s$ by $\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}$, and rewrite the formula without introducing $s$:

$$A = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c-d)(a+b-c+d)(a-b+c+d)(-a+b+c+d) - 16abcd \cos^2 \left(\frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2}\right)}$$

This is an extremely unwieldy formula and unmanageable for general use. Thus, we can see that writing out the formula in full is a bad idea, which is apparent as we generalize the formula. On the other hand, the standard form, is easy to state and work with and more useful, and hence I think the preference over other forms.

Comment: I will look this over more carefully today.

Answer (score 2):

You need to see the proof of that formula. If the proof has not to do directly with the concept of semiperimeter, than it means that two equivalent ways writting that formula are of the same power (substantially speaking). One of the proves is in this link here: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Heron/HeronProofAlg.html and it has to do nothing with the concept of perimeter, so I can say that it doesn't have a substantial difference on the way you write the Heron's formula.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is the same as changing

$$
e^{i\pi } + 1 = 0
$$

to

$$
e^{\frac{i\tau}{2}} + 1 = 0.
$$

The first one widely believed to be the most beautiful formula in mathematics.
Although the may be the same, and although many schools use Tau in mathematics, you lose a sense of beauty and simplicity that you had in the first formula.

In Heron's formula, you have a similar situation. The first formula gives the average math-lover who first sees the formula a sense a unity, beauty, simplicity, and astonishment at the raw simplicity of the formula. On the other hand, the second formula still requires that you memorize the same exact basic principle: add them all, lose the a, lose the b, lose the c. When students memorize the formula, this is what they will remember.

Be honest with yourself and remember the first time you saw the formula. Kind of cool, right? The uniqueness, beauty, and unity of it? While the first formula seems cleaner, the second seems a bit more disorganized.

Another way of thinking of it is why we write 5x instead of x5. They mean the same thing, according to the associative property of multiplication. They both would work. But one is just the way it's done.

I'm sorry if this is a bit dissatisfying. If all else failed to persuade you, Heron wrote the final formula that way when making it, so maybe it just hasn't come to question because of a. lack of importance or b. respect for it's creator.